# Inline Clickable List Layout in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to create a sort of inline list of clickable text blocks in Android Studio. Below is the closest image I could find to the effect I would like. How would I achieve such an effect?

The information shown will be just a string, however clicking on this will take the user to another activity. It would be good if the text blocks also had a background, by the looks of it this app uses an image as the background, which should be fairly easy to set if the list is made from text views. I just don't know how to make a list with variable length inline objects.

[image: here]

Comment: You can show your code for it .

Comment: @KeLiuyue I don't have any code. Just an empty activity with a list view. However a list view only shows one item per line. I can show more (I can't find the link right now, but you can display multiple columns), but then it just turns into a grid of items; which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout
What I was looking for was specifically a horiztonal, wrapping, inline list.